# Finite element convergence rates for mixed problems

Tags: linear-pde, limits-and-convergence, fluid-dynamics

I've coded up a Stokes Flow problem using finite elements and am in the process of verifying that it works. I'm just not sure what convergence rate I should be expecting as I globally refine the mesh.

I know for scalar problems using linear basis functions I'd expect order $h^2$ convergence ($h$ is element size), and using quadratic basis functions I'd expect order $h^3$ convergence in the $L^2$ norm and one power less in the $H^1$ seminorm. The problem I'm having now is that when coding Stokes flow I used the Taylor-Hood element which uses linears for the pressure and quadratic for the velocity components. Is it as simple as the velocities converging at $h^3$ and the pressure at order $h^2$?

Comment: This question is gathering some close votes (though none from me).  It may find a better reception at scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't understand why it would be closed here, but I will try at the scicomp stackexchange. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, it's now been posted on SciComp: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14156 (The usual way of things would have been to flag and ask for migration to avoid double content; not sure how that works for a beta site, though.)

Comment: It looks like SciComp has answered this satisfactorily.